# Looping a json encode filtered by type

Tags: php, javascript

I create a json encode in PHP like this:

```
$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table") or die(mysql_error());
$data = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
            $data[$row['id']][0] = $row['g'];
            $data[$row['id']][1] = $row['w'];
            $data[$row['id']][2] = $row['s'];
            $data[$row['id']][3] = $row['name'];
            $data[$row['id']][4] = $row['type'];
            }
$data4 = json_encode($data);
```

I assign it to a js variable: var bdata;

So what im trying to do is now loop the content filtered by [4] = type.

This is my loop:

```
 for(var key in bdata){
 //stuff here
 }
```

But this will loop all of them... but I want to loop only ones that have a [4] (type) of a certain value lets say the value was "2".

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: what do you mean by `But this will loop all of them` ?

Comment: It will loop through all the keys in bdata. Rather than only the ones where ['id'][4] = a specific value.

Comment: This is because you are looping it that way. Just add an `if` option in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through your rows. Not your columns. For each row there is a certain column named type. If you want to process it you can fetch it. They way you are constructing the JSON, it'll soon be enough unreadable at JS side that you'll pull you hair.

So Its better to have named keys.

You should have done it in this way,

```
$get = mysql_query("SELECT id, g, w, s, name, type FROM $table") 
    or die(mysql_error());
// If you only need to fetch the type then just list `type` on the above list.
$data = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
            $data[] = $row;
            // or
            // $data[$row['id']] = $row;
        }
$data4 = json_encode($data);
```

On the JS end.

```
for(var key in bdata){
    var type = bdata[key].type;
    // process type
}
```

Comment: Isn't this still looping all of the rows? Rather than just the ones with specific types? The less looping will be the best option to reduce inefficiency ?

Comment: Which loop you are talking about? php or JS?

Comment: This is not only premature optimization but also invalid! The way I show, you can easily get the `type` of 3rd row by `bdata[3].type`. How  else you want to access?? if you want to get all the `types` then it should be a loop. If you just want to extract an array that contains **only** `type`, then why not specify only `type` in SELECT sql? did you see my comment in the source code above?

Comment: Insert this sample data `{12:{"id":"12", "g":"g12", "w":"w12", "s":"s12", "name":"a name", "key":"some key"},
13:{"id":"13", "g":"g2", "w":"w2", "s":"s2", "name":"another name", "key":"some key 2"}}` in http://json.bloople.net/

Comment: I can't use it in SQL because i use ajax requests to grab it, i don't want hundreads of requests being sent to my server. I'd rather just grab them all once then filter it out in JS

Answer (score 2):

You should filter the array in php and pass the filtered array to a JS-Variable:

```
function filter($item) {
    return $item[4] == $whateverYouWant;
}
$data4 = json_encode(array_filter($data, "filter"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the entire array is stored in a single variable in JS, you will have to loop through all key-value pairs, whether they have the ID you want or not.

You would need to check each kvp for the ID you're looking for. Something like this

```
foreach(var key in bdata)
{
   if (key.id === 4)
   {
     //do your stuff here
   }
}
```

Looping this way is very cheap so there is no point in spending too much time to optimize this by skipping some elements altogether.

Comment: Is this more efficient than the suggestion below ?

Comment: Are you sure this will work? `key` should be `$row['id']`. see OPs code.

Comment: @Dave: the other answer is doing the filtering on server side, my example is doing it on client side. Both will be equally efficient +/- a few nanoseconds

Comment: @Shiplu: The loop is in Javascript. At this point, the PHP associative array no longer exists. It is now looping through a JSON object

Comment: The if-condition should be `(bdata[key][4] === ...)`.
If you never need the whole data on the client side filtering the php array is more efficient as you don't have to pass the whole data to the client-side.
Otherwise a solution like this is inevitable.

Comment: @Jasd: You make a good point. If filtering can be done at either end, it is better to do it at server side so as not to send excess data over the tubez

Comment: @xbonez Look carefully OP's code. There is not non-numeric key in the `$data`. When its json encoded. Its becomes object with numeric keys. so `key.id` does not exists. here `key` is numeric. You access it by `bdata[key]`. If one of his $row[id] is 2. `bdata[2]` will be found. Then you access `type` by `bdata[key][4]`.

Comment: Well the entire list kinda is needed otherwise i have to make more requests to the server when the data is needed, from my knowledge less requests is a better choice? 

So surely for reduces server load/lag etc client filtering would be wiser no ?

Comment: If you need all the data then it's wiser to transfer all at once I guess. So do the filtering on the client side.